# How to combine two query grouped differently into one output

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm new to SQL queries and have been thrown in the deep end!

I have two queries which I need to merge together. One performs three calculations *(sum as WGHours, count as WGCount, sum/count as WGAvg)* and groups the output by 2 columns: *work group and priority.* The other performs the same calculations *(PHours, PCOunt, PAvg but only groups by one column - priority*. This is so I can find the total figure for each priority so i can finally divide **WGAvg / PAvg** to produce **a %**.

I can create both queries individually, but need to merge the output of both together so that I can use them in one table. I've tried UNION ALL but it doesn't produce the output I need, which is:

```
WORK_GROUP, PRIORITY, WGHOURS, WGCount, WGAvg, PHours, PCount, PAvg
```

Any idea how I do this? I've tried using a solution I found on here but get an **oracle error telling me that the command is no properly ended**:

```
SELECT    One.OPriority,
      WorkGroup,
      AverageHours,
      WoCount,
      Divis 
FROM (Select  CORVU.MSV620.ORIG_PRIORITY as OPriority,
            CORVU.MSV620.WORK_GROUP as WorkGroup,
            SUM(CORVU.MSV621.ACT_LAB_HRS) AS AverageHours, 
            COUNT(CORVU.MSV621.WORK_ORDER) AS WoCount, 
            CAST(SUM(CORVU.MSV621.ACT_LAB_HRS) / COUNT(CORVU.MSV621.WORK_ORDER) AS DECIMAL (38, 2)) AS Divis
    FROM    CORVU.MSV620, CORVU.MSV621
    WHERE  CORVU.MSV620.WORK_ORDER = CORVU.MSV621.WORK_ORDER
    GROUP BY CORVU.MSV620.ORIG_PRIORITY, CORVU.MSV620.WORK_GROUP) AS one
JOIN (
      SELECT  CORVU.MSV620.ORIG_PRIORITY as OPriority, 
      CAST(SUM(CORVU.MSV621.ACT_LAB_HRS) / COUNT(CORVU.MSV621.WORK_ORDER) AS DECIMAL (38, 2)) AS DivisOP
      FROM     CORVU.MSV620, CORVU.MSV621
      WHERE  CORVU.MSV620.WORK_ORDER = CORVU.MSV621.WORK_ORDER AND (CORVU.MSV620.WORK_GROUP IN ('ENGA01', 'ENGA02', 'ENGA04', 'ENGA05', 'ENGA06', 
           'ENGA08')) AND (CORVU.MSV620.ACCOUNT_CODE LIKE '%B01%') AND (CORVU.MSV621.ACT_LAB_HRS > 0) AND (NOT (CORVU.MSV620.STD_JOB_NO IN ('ELE995', 
           'MEC995', 'ICA995'))) AND (CORVU.MSV620.ORIG_PRIORITY IN ('CH', 'CS', 'T0', 'T1', 'T2', 'T3', 'T4')) AND 
           (CORVU.MSV620.CLOSED_DT >= TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MONTH'), - 1), 'yyyymmdd')) AND 
           (CORVU.MSV620.CLOSED_DT <= TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE + 30, 'MONTH') - 1, - 1), 'yyyymmdd'))
        GROUP BY CORVU.MSV620.ORIG_PRIORITY) as two
WHERE     one.CORVU.MSV620.ORIG_PRIORITY = two.CORVU.MSV620.ORIG_PRIORITY;
```

Comment: Which dbms?  Oracle or sql server?

Answer (score 2):

In your query you are using `join`.  This then expects an `on` clause rather than a `where` clause.  This might fix your problem:

```
SELECT    One.OPriority,
      WorkGroup,
      AverageHours,
      WoCount,
      Divis 
FROM (Select  CORVU.MSV620.ORIG_PRIORITY as OPriority,
            CORVU.MSV620.WORK_GROUP as WorkGroup,
            SUM(CORVU.MSV621.ACT_LAB_HRS) AS AverageHours, 
            COUNT(CORVU.MSV621.WORK_ORDER) AS WoCount, 
            CAST(SUM(CORVU.MSV621.ACT_LAB_HRS) / COUNT(CORVU.MSV621.WORK_ORDER) AS DECIMAL (38, 2)) AS Divis
    FROM    CORVU.MSV620, CORVU.MSV621
    WHERE  CORVU.MSV620.WORK_ORDER = CORVU.MSV621.WORK_ORDER
    GROUP BY CORVU.MSV620.ORIG_PRIORITY, CORVU.MSV620.WORK_GROUP) one
------------------------------------------------------------------^
JOIN (
      SELECT  CORVU.MSV620.ORIG_PRIORITY as OPriority, 
      CAST(SUM(CORVU.MSV621.ACT_LAB_HRS) / COUNT(CORVU.MSV621.WORK_ORDER) AS DECIMAL (38, 2)) AS DivisOP
      FROM     CORVU.MSV620, CORVU.MSV621
      WHERE  CORVU.MSV620.WORK_ORDER = CORVU.MSV621.WORK_ORDER AND (CORVU.MSV620.WORK_GROUP IN ('ENGA01', 'ENGA02', 'ENGA04', 'ENGA05', 'ENGA06', 
           'ENGA08')) AND (CORVU.MSV620.ACCOUNT_CODE LIKE '%B01%') AND (CORVU.MSV621.ACT_LAB_HRS > 0) AND (NOT (CORVU.MSV620.STD_JOB_NO IN ('ELE995', 
           'MEC995', 'ICA995'))) AND (CORVU.MSV620.ORIG_PRIORITY IN ('CH', 'CS', 'T0', 'T1', 'T2', 'T3', 'T4')) AND 
           (CORVU.MSV620.CLOSED_DT >= TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MONTH'), - 1), 'yyyymmdd')) AND 
           (CORVU.MSV620.CLOSED_DT <= TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE + 30, 'MONTH') - 1, - 1), 'yyyymmdd'))
        GROUP BY CORVU.MSV620.ORIG_PRIORITY) two
---------------------------------------------^
      on one.CORVU.MSV620.ORIG_PRIORITY = two.CORVU.MSV620.ORIG_PRIORITY;  
------^ was WHERE
```

EDIT:

I also removed the `as` (as you already note in a comment).  Oracle does not allow `as` for table aliases.

Comment: Thank you for your help - but I`m still getting an error telling me that the command is not properly ended. This is from Oracle SQl developer 15.

Comment: @NeilDeeley . . . In that case, start by running each subquery independently to be sure they are syntactically correct.  The structure of combining them looks ok.

Comment: @NeilDeeley . . . I might guess that you want a `left outer join` or a `full outer join`.

Comment: Crikey, you are quick! Thanks for your help - I did remove the AS but hadn't joined the other columns so got some strange results. Cheers for everything!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the second query as a field using a (sub)select, like this:

```
select a.name, a.address, sum(a.xxx), 
(select avg(b.amount) from costs b where b.id=a.id)
from clients a
where ... ;
```